# Collection View Cell Size Dependent on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, height, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `Cell` containing a `UITextView`. I want the size of the cell to depend on the height of the TextView (so that scrolling isn't necessary and all the text is always visible). 
I am trying this:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if (indexPath.row < myComments!.count) {

        if let messageText = myComments![indexPath.row].text  {
            let size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width / 2, 100)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)
            return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, estimatedFrame.height + 50)
        }
    }
    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 100)

}
```

however it isn't really working. Sometimes the height is way too big, sometimes its too small and I still have to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextView's sizeThatFits method. It calculate exactly size the UITextView need.